# webpack public folder for images

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In order to start using react, i added Webpack and Babel to my node app.
I imported all my scripts to one script and set it as entry in webpack.config.js which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

entry: './src/App.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'app.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
}

};
```

when starting the webpack-dev-server, the scripts cannot find the images located in my public folder (which is being pointed as the static folder in the server index.js). I tried adding - publicPath: "/public/" in the output but then it couldn't even find app.js anymore. what's the best way of using my images in Webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put them in your source directory and require them!

src/exampleImage.jpg = your image

src/ExampleImage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import imageUrl from './exampleImage.jpg';

export default class ExampleImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <img src={imageUrl} />;
  }
}
```

Add the correct loader to your loaders array (don't forget to `npm install file-loader`):

```
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
    loaders: ['file'],
  }
```

And you're done! Webpack will automatically copy the image over to the right directory (where your built scripts will be) and make sure imageUrl is right and works.

Cool bonus: you can automatically minify images with image-webpack-loader, and do things like automatic filename hashing with file-loader for long-term caching. Just check their documentations for more information!